# What lies at the very edge of the expanding universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe, dark-energy, multiverse, observable-universe

We all know that the universe is expanding at an accelerated rate and it might appear much like a soap bubble. That is where the phrase *dark energy* whose essence is unknown and which is thought to have caused this comes from. But that is not what this question is really about. If we could stand at the very edge of the expanding universe...

1. What would we see just outside of it? Pure blackness or other expanding bubbles of multiverses?
2. How about at the very edge? Would there be a membrane of some kind?
3. What about at the inside of the edge? Of course this last question
   is easy to tackle because we would just see our own universe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)

Comment: @ACuriousMind Please do not abuse your privileges. This post is not a duplicate of the other. Re-read both posts again. Mine goes into depth and asks very different questions.

Comment: Read the answer to the question I linked. There is no edge, there is nothing the universe expands into, and the term "outside" is meaningless. You question is based exactly on the same misconception as the idea that the Big Bang happened at a point.

Comment: Edge of the universe?  https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/seuforum/faq.htm#s1

Comment: The answers may be the same but they are two entirely different questions asked. Again I say re-read the posted questions to each post. They are not the same.

Comment: @ACuriousMind

By the way I do agree that the universe did not begin from a single point in space because space did not yet exist for our universe but since its expansion it does appear to be moving away from a point somewhere inside our universe.

Secondly I am very much aware the no one knows what lies beyond our expanding universe (what is it expanding into) but I posted this question to see what others thought may be possible. In other words this question is as much a philosophical one as it is scientific.

Please remove the duplicate.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Sorry about that. I thought you duped it but you only commented on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What would we see just outside of it? Pure blackness or other expanding bubbles of multiverses?*

Outside our [particle horizon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_horizon) we assume that everything is more or less the same like where we are, at least if the assumption of [homogenity and isotropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_principle) holds. If we live in a [multiverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse#Max_Tegmark.27s_four_levels) there might also be other laws of nature beyond or horizon, but there is no way to really test this. Anyway, more speculations on this can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANCN7vr9FVk&list=PL7Yaf7nQHP3DSNGnCWvQOgz5A_EtQ-6sr&index=2) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PC0zHIf2Gkw&index=5&list=PLV4bq2vDW15-DVXXIhhl-9ipYAytLpNJL).

> *How about at the very edge?*

The universe has no edges. If it is [finitely curved](http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/cosmo/lectures/lec15.html) you always get back to where you started from when you move in a straight line (except if [superluminal expansion](http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0310808v2.pdf) confines you to a [horizon](http://yukterez.ist.org/lcdm/#plot) smaller than the cirumference of you dimension).

Comment: English please! I am just a layman. o_~